# Programmatically Adding LinearLayouts to ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a xml view that contains a **ScrollView**(with a child **LinearLayout**).

```
...
   <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/image_holder"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
...
```

I am trying to dynamically add some images, I want 3 per row.

```
private void createDice(LinearLayout ll, Integer required) {
    ArrayList<Integer> images = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    images.add(R.drawable.one);
    images.add(R.drawable.two);
    images.add(R.drawable.three);
    images.add(R.drawable.four);
    images.add(R.drawable.five);
    images.add(R.drawable.six);

    ScreenHelper screen = new ScreenHelper(MainActivity.this);
    Map<String, Float> s = screen.getScreenSize();
    Integer maxPerRow = (int) (s.get("width") / 90); // images are 89px wide
    Log.d(TAG, "max across::"+maxPerRow);

    Integer rows = (required / maxPerRow);
    Log.d(TAG, "rows::"+rows);
    for (int i=0; i < rows; i++) {
        Log.d(TAG, "i::"+i);
        // create linear layout for row
        LinearLayout llAlso = new LinearLayout(this);
        llAlso.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        //llAlso.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        for (int j=0; j < 3; j++) {
            Log.d(TAG, "j::"+j);
            // create/add image for the row
            ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
            iv.setImageResource(images.get(i));
            llAlso.addView(iv);
        }
        // add to main layout
        ll.addView(llAlso, i);
        Log.d(TAG, "adding to main view");
    }
}
```

I am testing with the **required** parameter value of 6.
The problem is that the first row of images gets added, but either the second isn't because it is getting added adjacent to the first row (and therefore off the screen) and not under it.

How to achieve my desired output?

Comment: It sounds like what you are trying to accomplish is very well suited for a `GridView`, and reason why you are opposed to using that?

Comment: @BrentHronik I am not opposed to using a GridView (now I know), but I still like to finish what I started even if if is not the best way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the orientation in your `image_holder` layout to `vertical`. By default, the orientation of a `LinearLayout` is `horizontal`. That means that all child views will be added in a horizontal row. Since your child layouts use `fill_parent` for their width, only one child can fit in the row. By switching it to `vertical`, your layouts are added in a vertical column instead of in a row. That allows more layouts to be visible.

Also you should consider to use a `GridLayout` instead. That is made for exactly this case.

Comment: @Rooneyl By default, the orientation of a `LinearLayout` is `horizontal`.  That means that all child views will be added in a horizontal row.  Since your child layouts use `fill_parent` for their width, only one child can fit in the row.  By switching it to `vertical`, your layouts are added in a vertical column instead of in a row.  That allows more layouts to be visible.